# How to do foreach loop through different variable in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a dynamic form which have dynamic input of textbox and variable of date,float and time.I want to insert those input dynamically into my sql table.
So here is the part of my code.I'm only able to loop through one variable,When i want to loop through the time and float,it face the conversion problem on float and time.(If any picture needed just let me know )

```
$ct = 0;
if ($_POST['Dates'] && $_POST['slct']) {
    foreach ($_POST['Dates'] as $value) {
        $values = $value;
        $dates = $_POST['Dates']; // for leave date
        $datess = $_POST['datess']; // for created date


        $Area = $_COOKIE['cooAreaCode'];
        $days = $_POST['slct'];

        $time = date("h:i a", strtotime($frtime));
        $times = date("h:i a", strtotime($totime));

        $frtime = $_POST['frtime'];
        $totime = $_POST['totime'];


        $link_mssql = odbc_connect(DB_HSATTEND, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $sql = "SELECT MAX(RefNo) as val from tblLeaveHeader";
        $res = odbc_exec($link_mssql, $sql);
        while (odbc_fetch_row($res)) {
            $count = odbc_result($res, "val");
        }
        odbc_free_result($res);

        $temp = sprintf('%08d', $count + 1);

        if (empty($_POST['frtime']) && empty($_POST['totime'])) {
            $sql3 = "INSERT INTO tblLeaveDetails (RefNo, LeaveType, Leavedd, Leaveday, LeaveFrmTime, LeaveToTime)  
               VALUES('$temp','$Leave','$values', '$days[$ct]', NULL, NULL)";
            $res = odbc_exec($link_mssql, $sql3);
            $ct++;
        } else {
            $sql2 = "INSERT INTO tblLeaveDetails (RefNo, LeaveType, Leavedd, Leaveday, LeaveFrmTime, LeaveToTime)  
               VALUES('$temp','$Leave','$values', '$days[$ct]', '$frtime[$ct]', '$totime[$ct]')";
            $res = odbc_exec($link_mssql, $sql2);
            $ct++;
        }
    }
}
```

Example of result in sql table

```
| ID   | Refno | Leavetype     | Leaveday | Leavdd     |frtime|totime
| 1    | 00001 | Annual Leave  | 1        | 2017-07-17 |3.00  | 7.00
| 2    | 00001 | Annual Leave | 1        | 2017-07-18 |4.00  | 6.00
```

Comment: Could you explain why you used a foreach ?

Comment: @ksjohn Because i need to do a looping to count all the value inside my form,to do repeating for some other fields as i shown in above table,in same refno it can have many different date and time,and also day could be either 1 or 0.5

Comment: Okay. Because I must say to you that you don't know what a foreach is or does. If you type `foreach ($_POST['Dates'] as $value) {}`, that means that - assuming that `$_POST['Dates']` is an array - each of the foreach's iteration will be put a different entry from `$_POST['Dates']` in `$value`. You don't use `$value` at all, and it doesn't even seem that `$_POST['Dates']` is an array. You should remove your foreach and your code will do the same things while being less messy.

Comment: @ksjohn if i remove the foreach how i can i manage to get all the input values from my form ?any suggestion ?

Comment: You foreach is useless as it is, you don't use it. You're supposed to put arrays in foreach and it will give you a different entry of the array each iteration. You don't seem to use your foreach on an arrayn and you never use the value you get from it. Just remove the foreach, you don't use it. I don't know how to be more clear.

Comment: Can you write some demo for me to do reference,if i wanna to do it in array.

Comment: `$arr = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'banana'); foreach ($array as $val) {echo $val,'-';} Output: one-two-three-banana`

Comment: @ksjohn i know what i'm wrong already,it's a very silly mistake i forget to change my input type to array ,that's why i keep cannot get the correct value.By the way,thanks you so much for suggestion provided